# Windows 10 Upgrade Assistant blank

Tags: windows-10, javascript, internet-explorer-11, windows-10-v1703

I am trying to do the Windows 10 Creators Update. I downloaded `Windows10Upgrade28085.exe` from [here](https://support.microsoft.com/nl-nl/help/4014184/windows-10-creators-update-here), ran it and got a perfectly blank screen, spare a Microsoft logo.

[image]

I could however right-click on the empty space, I get an Internet-Explorer style menu, from which I can view the Properties.

[image]

I figured that I might as wel try and open the page shown in the Properties dialog using Internet Explorer (not my browser of choice, but Chrome would not display anything either, but I think that's just because the page is not made for Chrome). My Internet Explorer homepage then told me that JavaScript was disabled/not present! Looking at the source of the Upgrade Assistant page, it indeed **should** use JavaScript, so I think that the lack of JavaScript is causing the Update Assistant not to work.

Then, I set out on enabling JavaScript. In Internet Options, I found that Active Scripting was still enabled. As a test, I set it to Prompt, and it would ask a bunch of times whether I wanted to run a script, and then didn't do anything.

Next, I figured I might have stuff disabled in Developer Options. I opened up Developer Options, and got a blank area where Developer Options *should* be.

I am running Internet Explorer with all add-ons disabled. I tried using `regsvr32 jscript.dll` which supposedly was successful but didn't help. I reinstalled Internet Explorer through the 'Programs and Features' -> 'Turn Windows features on or off' menu, to no avail.

How do I proceed?

Comment: get a 1703 ISO and do here the upgrade

Comment: It appears that for whatever reason, the method used to download the ISO by the upgrade assistance, is being blocked on your machine likely by some administrative setting.  I suspect the Media Creation Tool would have the same problems.  Manually, download the ISO yourself from Microsoft, and mount the ISO and install the upgrade.